# Searching for strings and locating the line numbers that strings are located in [PYTHON]

Tags: python

How can I search for strings and locate the line numbers that strings are located in?

For example

```
>>> findlinenb('example.txt', ['desktop', 'connection', 'processor'])
desktop in 23
connection in 35, 38, 35
processor in 4, 5, 6, 8
```

My code:

```
def findlinenb (filename, list):
file = open(filename, "r")
content = file.read()
for i in list:
    if content.find(i):
        print (i, "in", content.count('\n') + 1)
```

Any ideas or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Peter

Comment: Simply `grep -n "your_string" your_file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['desktop', 'connection', 'processor']
occurrences = dict((w, []) for w in words)
with open("example.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        for w in words:
            if w in line:
                occurrences[w].append(i)
print occurrences.items()
```